# How do i get time difference in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Let's say i am importing a time from sql with

```
<input type="hidden" name="dte_assignment" id="dte_assingment" runat="server" />
```

i want to get the difference in time from the sql time to the current time.  How would i do that?
I need to get the time so that if it goes over 24 hours something is blocked.

Thanks

Comment: You can subtract one DateTime from the other and use the resulting `TimeSpan`? Or are you trying to do this in javascript?

Comment: Pretty standard forward... Goto msdn and consider some information about time handling instead of asking for a solution for specific problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim difference As System.TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(yourTime)
If difference.TotalHours > 24 Then
   ' block something
End If
```